# How to scrape the data of two tables sitting side by side in a webpage?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've written a script in `python` in combination with `BeautiflSoup` using `.select()` to parse the tabular data from some html elements. The data in reality are within two tables. When I open that site I can see that the two tables stay side by side like ***[you can see in this image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5t4ndmwjobofru4/output.jpg?dl=0)***. I marked the second table with a pencil to let you know that it is in reality the second table sitting close to each other.

However, when I execute my below script, I get the output one after another. How can I source them like they are visible in that image, meaning side by side.

I could not paste the html elements as they are too huge to fit to the below area. However, that can be found ***[in this link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/t7hr8rgra933n1s/htmldoc.txt?dl=0)***. Could not share the website link as it required log in to reach the data.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

htmldoc = """replace_with_above_elements"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(htmldoc,"lxml")
for items in soup.select("tbody.Table2__tbody tr"):
    data = [item.text for item in items.select("td")]
    print(data)
```

Btw, the two tables are of similar structures.

Current output:

```
['PG', 'Empty', '', '--', '']
['SG', 'Eric GordonHouSG', '', '@LAC', '7:00 AM']
['SF', 'Taurean PrinceAtlSF', '', '@Cle', '4:00 AM']
['PF', 'Empty', '', '--', '']
['C', 'Jusuf NurkicPorC', '', '--', '']
['UTIL', 'Paul GeorgeOKCSF', '', 'Sac', '5:00 AM']
['UTIL', 'Gary HarrisDenSG', '', 'GS', '6:00 AM']
['UTIL', "D'Angelo RussellBknPG, SG", '', '--', '']
['Bench', 'Damian LillardPorPG', '', '--', '']
['Bench', 'Devin BookerPhxSG', '', '--', '']
['Bench', 'Deandre AytonPhxC', '', '--', '']
['Bench', 'Mike ConleyMemPG', '', '--', '']
['Bench', 'Trevor ArizaPhxSF', '', '--', '']
['Bench', 'Serge IbakaTorPF', '', '--', '']
['IR', 'Isaiah ThomasODenPG', '', 'GS', '6:00 AM']
['--', '--/--', '--', '--/--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--']
['30.5', '5.5/13.5', '.407', '3.0/3.0', '1.000', '1.0', '2.0', '1.0', '0.0', '1.0', '0.5', '15.0', '0.82', '53.1', '+5.0']
['27.5', '8.5/15.0', '.567', '4.0/4.0', '1.000', '3.5', '5.0', '4.5', '1.5', '0.0', '5.0', '24.5', '5.76', '49.2', '+10.8']
['--', '--/--', '--', '--/--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--']
['20.0', '6.5/13.0', '.500', '1.0/1.0', '1.000', '0.0', '8.5', '1.0', '1.5', '0.5', '2.0', '14.0', '2.05', '78.6', '-5.1']
['37.5', '8.0/25.0', '.320', '4.0/5.5', '.727', '3.5', '5.0', '4.5', '3.0', '0.0', '4.0', '23.5', '1.80', '99.8', '-0.1']
['34.5', '6.5/15.5', '.419', '5.5/6.0', '.917', '0.5', '3.5', '3.0', '1.0', '0.5', '0.5', '19.0', '3.08', '76.4', '-5.5']
['30.0', '4.3/12.3', '.351', '1.3/1.7', '.800', '1.7', '4.3', '6.0', '0.7', '0.7', '3.0', '11.7', '2.43', '81.2', '-6.3']
['32.5', '9.0/18.0', '.500', '8.0/8.0', '1.000', '2.5', '4.0', '6.5', '0.5', '0.5', '1.5', '28.5', '8.47', '99.9', '0.0']
['34.5', '8.5/17.0', '.500', '9.5/11.5', '.826', '3.5', '3.0', '7.0', '0.5', '0.0', '4.5', '30.0', '4.30', '99.7', '+0.2']
['29.5', '5.0/9.0', '.556', '1.5/2.0', '.750', '0.0', '9.0', '3.5', '0.5', '0.5', '1.0', '11.5', '2.14', '98.4', '-0.2']
['27.0', '4.5/12.0', '.375', '2.5/3.0', '.833', '2.0', '3.0', '7.0', '0.5', '0.0', '0.5', '13.5', '2.09', '92.2', '-2.6']
['33.0', '4.5/9.5', '.474', '1.0/1.0', '1.000', '3.0', '5.5', '4.0', '0.5', '0.5', '1.5', '13.0', '3.31', '40.9', '+31.2']
['29.3', '5.3/11.3', '.471', '4.0/5.7', '.706', '0.7', '7.3', '1.0', '1.0', '1.7', '1.7', '15.3', '5.29', '36.0', '+2.4']
['--', '--/--', '--', '--/--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '37.1', '-17.9']
```

***Expected output is visible in the above image link.***

Comment: Share current and desired output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to handle two tables as below:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmldoc,"lxml")

tables = soup.select("tbody.Table2__tbody")

for left, right in zip(tables[0].select("tr"), tables[1].select("tr")):
    data = [item.text for item in left.select("td")] + [item.text for item in right.select("td")]
    print(data)
```

Comment: I cannot test it right now, so let me know if below is not working properly

Comment: When you intervene, there is no room for confusion @sir Andersson.